# How to display facebook like count on website in specific number instead of K?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I am using facebook sdk to display facebook like count in my website footer.

Now I have more that 1k likes but it showing 1k instead of specific number.

So I can display facebook likes on my webpage in specific number instead of 'k'?

Comment: No there is no way to change that

Comment: Thanks. Is there any facebook developer forum so I can post same question in that forum?

Comment: Asking in another place will not change the answer. You could only go and request the number of likes from the API yourself, and then display it in the form you like. (But then it will not have any like button functionality any more, but will be static only.)